# Which factor should I take into priority to determine reactivity of of Halides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity

Such as in the attached question I was taking into account the stability of the carbocations (by the number of resonating structures) formed after removal of Chlorine from and concluded to be the order I>II>III>IV>V the answer states the order to be I>III>IV>V>II

Can conclude what factors they are priority to. Help needed  [image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of aromaticity? The **Hückel rule** can be applied to charged species too!

Comment: Yes I know Huckel rule. Kindly, enlighten me the procedure. In which way I should apply the rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to consider the stability of the carbocations obtained after chloride leaves, we can, as Klaus commented already, use Hückels rule, which more or less states that fully $\ce{sp^2}$ (i.e. usually $\ce{sp^2}$, as long as there is atleast one full p-orbital) hyberdized  compounds with $4n+2$ electrons are particularly stable or *aromatic*. The same type of compounds that have $4n$ are particularly unstable, *anti-aromatic*. Of course a carbocation has an empty p-orbital, so compunds I and III will be aromatic and compound II anti-aromatic. Compound I is fully benzenoid and also less strained than compound III and will hence be more stable, so I > III. Then follows the allylic carbocation IV which is obviously more stable than its non-allylic counterpart V. And last but not least the anti-aromatic compound II.

In conclusion I > III > IV > V > II, as the answer indicated.

Comment: shouldn't it be 4n + 2

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest the edit.